# Manually implementing RSA in Java using BigInteger

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, biginteger, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to implement RSA encryption and decryption of files in Java using BigInteger.

I have my parameters p, q, e, n, d

I read a file into a byte[]

```
System.out.println("Opening file: " + infile);
File file = new File(infile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
int filelength = (int)file.length();
byte[] filecontent = new byte[filelength];
fis.read(filecontent);
fis.close();
```

And then make a BigInteger from that byte[]

```
BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger(filecontent);
```

Then encryption is simply

```
BigInteger ciphertext = plaintext.modPow(e, n);
```

And I write the ciphertext to a new encrypted file

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
fos.write(ciphertext.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

Decryption is pretty much the same

```
BigInteger plaintext = ciphertext.modPow(d, n);
```

This worked perfectly fine when I first tested it with a small text file. It encrypted and decrypted just fine.  However as I started to test with some other files like a jpg or zip, everything fell apart.  I can't pinpoint the problem debugging but I do notice sometimes the conversion from the file byte[] to BigInteger results in an empty BigInteger object.

Is there something I have to do to the byte[] before encryption?

Comment: What do you mean by 'everything fell apart'?

Comment: You'd better split the file content into chunks and encrypt them separately.

Comment: I would get empty encrypted files and of course subsequently, incorrect decrypted files.
Any suggestions on how to split the file?

Comment: You should encrypt files using a combination of RSA and a symmetric cipher, e.g. AES in CBC mode. For RSA you should be using using OAEP mode padding if possible, although PKCS#1 padding is easier for learning purposes. Both have been described in the publicly available (and pretty readable) PKCS#1 standards from RSA labs. Encrypting a file using just modular exponentiation is learning how *not* to perform encryption. RSA without padding over large data is bunk.

Comment: Are you just trying to learn, or do you have a real application in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this , you need to divide the file into chunk, which means for example take  every 256 bit as a part  and encrypt it ., and so on.